# C++: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, access-violation

I was wondering if I can get some help on my program. As stated in the title, I'm getting an access violation in my program. I realize that it has something to do with dereferencing a garbage pointer, and I'm pretty sure I've narrowed down the line that its breaking on, I'm just not sure why it's actually breaking, and how to fix it. The code is as follows:

```
void determineInputType(char input[kMaxUserInput])
{
    char* flag = NULL;
    if (*(flag = strchr(input, '.')) != NULL)
    { 
        double grade = 0;
        if ((sscanf(input, "%lf", grade)) == 1)  // problem is on this line
        {
        //rest of the code continues here
```

How I'm getting the input is here:

```
void getUserInput(char* userInput)
{
    printf("Enter a student's grade: ");
    fgets(userInput, kMaxUserInput, stdin);
    clearCRLF(userInput);

}
```

and finally the main:

```
int main(void)
{
    char userInput[kMaxUserInput] = { 0 };
    getUserInput(userInput);
    determineInputType(userInput);

    return 0;
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as it's been stumping me for a while. Thanks so much for your time, if there's anything else I need to post, let me know.

Comment: I also noticed another problem in this line: `if (*(flag = strchr(input, '.')) != NULL)` ... you are dereferencing the pointer `flag` while it may be `NULL`. You should change it into `if ((flag = strchr(input, '.')) != NULL)`

Comment: Yeah that was me testing to see if that would fix the problem before, I should probably get rid of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scanf` family requires you to supply a *pointer* to the value you want populated:

```
if ((sscanf(input, "%lf", &grade)) == 1)  // problem is no longer on this line
```

The way you have it, you set `grade` to zero then use *that* as the pointer.

The relevant part of the standard (C99 on which C++11 defers to) is `7.19.6.2 /12` (my bold):

> `a,e,f,g` - Matches an optionally signed floating-point number, infinity, or `NaN`, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the `strtod` function. **The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to floating.**
>
> `l` (ell) - Specifies that ... a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier applies to an argument with type **pointer to double;** ...